# C++ typeid(x).name() returns ph

Tags: c++, pointers, types

What data type is Ph? I know i is int, s is short, l is long, etc... but whats ph mean?

The data type of the object is `uint_8 *`

Comment: Probably `p` means pointer, and `h` probably means `unsigned char`.

Comment: probably Hungarian for pointer to half word.

Answer (score 12):

It's a mangled type string. If you want something more human readable, you need to pass it into a demangler like (if you're using gcc) `c++filt` (if out of process) or `abi::__cxa_demangle()` if in code:

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char * name = abi::__cxa_demangle("Ph", 0, 0, 0);
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
    free(name);
}
```

This prints:

```
unsigned char*
```

Which is correct.